# Unit testing RxJava code with multiple external calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, rx-java, reactive-programming

Here is some RxJava code that I want to test:

```
public void triggerCancelOrderJob() {
        couchConnector()
            .findAbandonedOpenOrders()
            .flatMap(results -> results.rows())
            .flatMap(
                row ->
                    Observable.just(row)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .map(
                            s -> return s.value())
                        .flatMap(
                            orderId -> {
                              return RxReactiveStreams.toObservable(
                                  serviceTokenCache
                                     .get(OrderApiConstants.SERVICE_TOKEN_CACHE_KEY)
                                      .flatMap(
                                          issueToken -> {
                                            return cancelOrderApiConnector()
                                                .invokeAPI(
                                                    RequestInputModel.builder().build(),
                                                    RequestInputModel.RequestBodyModel.builder().build());
                                          }));
                            }))
            .subscribe(//additional code)
```

So what's happening is that I  run an async CB query, get an `Observable< AsyncN1qlQueryResult >`, then for each row I call call two external services one after the another (first call to the `serviceTokenCache` and second call to the `cancelOrderApiConnector`). Each row runs in a separate `IO` thread.

Note: `serviceTokenCache.get()` and `cancelOrderApiConnector().invokeAPI()` return a `Mono` respectively.

I cannot figure out how to test this code. What all components need to be tested? Since each row will run in its separate thread, I cannot wrap my head around how to test such asynchronous code.

Comment: Mock the external calls using `Mockito`

Comment: Firstly, inject the schedulers instead of using `Schedulers.io()`. This will make it much easier to unit test. Secondly, mock or inject the code for the external calls. Also, you using the nested `flatMap()` incorrectly or redundantly -- it isn't doing what you think it is doing.